# Compact embedding in $L^2((0,\infty),rdr)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $H$ be the closure of $C^{\infty}_0(0,\infty)$ with respect to the inner product
$$(f,g)=\int_0^{\infty}\left(f'(r)g'(r)+h(r)f(r)g(r)\right)rdr,$$
and induced norm $||f||_H^2=(f,f)$, and where $h(r)=1/r^2+\lambda$ with $\lambda>0$. Is this space compactly embedded in $L^2((0,\infty),rdr)$?

Here is what I am able to show:

1. $H$ is continuously embedded in $L^2((0,\infty),rdr)$ and in $W^{1,2}((0,\infty),rdr)$, i.e., 
   \begin{align}
   \int_0^{\infty}f^2(r)rdr\leq\int_0^{\infty}\left(f_r^2(r)+f^2(r)\right)rdr\leq \max\left\{1,\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\right\}||f||_H^2.
   \end{align}
2. $H$ is embedded in $W_{loc}^{1,2}(0,\infty)$. So $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.
3. Every $f\in H$ satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(\infty)=0$.
4. Using $f(0)=0$, we have that $H$ is embedded in $L^{\infty}[0,\infty)$.

Comment: That it is a compact embedding or not should depend on the ratio $\frac{\|\phi(.-a)\|_H}{\|\phi(.-a)\|_{L^2}}$ as $a \to \infty$

Comment: @reuns What is $\phi$? Can you provide more details or a reference?

Comment: The ratio shouldn't depend so much on $\phi$ compactly supported. If the ratio doesn't $\to \infty$ then the embedding is not compact since $\frac{\phi(.-n)}{\|\phi(.-n)\|_H}$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence in $L^2$.